# [Java]Does indexOf use equals?

Tags: java, overriding, equals, indexof

I was wondering how the method indexOf of an ArrayList is implemented. In fact I have override the equals method like this:

```
public class CustomObject {
@Override 
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if(o instanceof CityLoader)
            return ((CityLoader)o).getName() == this.name;
        else if (o instanceof String)
            return this.name.equals((String)o);         
        return false;
    }
}
```

I though this will avoid me to override also the indexOf method but it seems I am totally wrong.
When I try

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> customObjects = new ArrayList<CustomObject>
... insert customobject into the arraylist ...
customObjects.indexOf(new String("name"))
```

indexOf return false but it should return true. (I checked the element I am looking for exists)

Am I totally wrong?

Comment: *"I was wondering how the method indexOf of an ArrayList is implemented"* You don't need to know how it's *implemented*, you need to know what the contract is. There's a tool for that: [The JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-), which says: *"Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))`, or -1 if there is no such index."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`equals` should never return true when the compared objects are not of the same type (in your case `CustomObject`'s `equals` should always return false when `o` is not an instance of `CustomObject`).

The implementation of `indexOf` happens to use `String`'s `equals` instead of your `CustomObject`'s `equals` when you pass a `String` to it, and `String`'s `equals` returns false when you pass to it a object that is not a `String`.

In addition, don't use `==` in comparison of Strings.

You should pass an instance of `CustomObject` to `indexOf` :

```
customObjects.indexOf(new CustomObject("name"))
```

(or whatever the constructor of `CustomObject` looks like)

Your `equals` method should look like this :

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof CityLoader))
        return false;
    CityLoader other = (CityLoader)o;
    return other.name.equals(this.name);
}
```

Comment: You are right! Should I override the String equals?

Comment: @user1315621 No, you can't. String is a final class.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems to be a terrible practise. I will avoid it. Thanks!

Comment: Just another question. If I want to override the indexOf method, will I have to do it in the CustomObject class or in a new class which extends ArrayList<CustomObject> ?

Comment: @user1315621 Probably doing it in `CustomObject `would do.

Comment: @user1315621 indexOf is a method of the `List` interface. You'll have to override it in a sub-class of the List implementation you are using (i.e. a sub-class of ArrayList in your case). It doesn't seem like a good idea though.

Comment: @user1315621 If you implement it in CustomObject, it won't be used when you call `customObjects.indexOf`, since `customObjects` is an ArrayList.

Comment: @user1315621 the solution here is _not to use `indexOf`._  Just write your own loop.  Don't try to use `indexOf(someTypeNotTheElementType)`, don't try to hack that into working, _just stop._

Comment: Downvote. `other.name` may be null and throw a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

```
customObjects.indexOf(new String("name"))
```

This is what you are doing wrong. You are looking for an index of a `String` inside a `CustomObject` object list.

From the java docs :

> ```
>  /**
>      * Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element
>      * in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.
>      * More formally, returns the lowest index <tt>i</tt> such that
>      * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>,
>      * or -1 if there is no such index.
>      *
>      * @param o element to search for
>      * @return the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>      *         this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element
>      * @throws ClassCastException if the type of the specified element
>      *         is incompatible with this list
>      *         (<a href="Collection.html#optional-restrictions">optional</a>)
>      * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this
>      *         list does not permit null elements
>      *         (<a href="Collection.html#optional-restrictions">optional</a>)
>      */
>     int indexOf(Object o);
> ```